# Некорректная работа python скрипта

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Решил написать небольшой скрипт по типу заполнения анкеты и что-то типа регистрации. Суть в том, что я не могу проверить данные которые внесены в `usr__login` (вносятся через `input` в функции `reg`). Т. е., я могу их вывести обычным `print()`, но при этом, при проверке через if, программа как будто не видит данные в usr__login.

UPD: Я думаю, что ошибка в функции login. Сижу, ищу ошибку.. Но так и не могу найти ее..

```
import colorama

usr__login = None
usr__pass = None


#auth form

def login():
    log__row = input("Enter your login: ")
    if log__row != usr__login : 
        print("Wrong login! Try again.")
        return login()
    elif log__row == usr__login :
        pass_row = input("Enter your password: ")
        if pass__row != usr__pass:
            print("Wrogn password! Try again.")
            return
        elif pass__row == usr__pass:
            print("Authorization is successful!")

#reg form

def reg():
    usr__login = input("Login: ")
    if len(usr__login) < 8 :
        print("Your login's so short, try again..")
        return reg()
    elif len(usr__login) >= 8:
        usr__pass = input("Password: ")
        if len(usr__pass) < 8:
            print("Your password's so short, try again..")
            usr__pass = input("Password: ")
        elif len(usr__pass) >= 8:
            print("Good! Your account has be created.")
            return login()
def start():
    start_a = input("Do you have an account? Yes(Y)/No(N)")

    if start_a == "Y":
        login()
    else:
        reg()

start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два способа решения вашей проблемы:

1. Самый простой - сделать переменные глобальными, то есть в начале функций `login()`, `reg()` и `start()` надо вписать такую строчку `global usr__pass, usr__login`

Готовый код с глобальными переменными:

```
import colorama

usr__login = None
usr__pass = None


#auth form

def login():
    global usr__pass, usr__login
    log__row = input("Enter your login: ")
    if log__row != usr__login :
        print("Wrong login! Try again.")
        return login()
    elif log__row == usr__login :
        pass__row = input("Enter your password: ")
        if pass__row != usr__pass:
            print("Wrogn password! Try again.")
            return
        elif pass__row == usr__pass:
            print("Authorization is successful!")

#reg form

def reg():
    global usr__pass, usr__login
    usr__login = input("Login: ")
    if len(usr__login) < 8 :
        print("Your login's so short, try again..")
        return reg()
    elif len(usr__login) >= 8:
        usr__pass = input("Password: ")
        if len(usr__pass) < 8:
            print("Your password's so short, try again..")
            return reg()
        elif len(usr__pass) >= 8:
            print("Good! Your account has be created.")
            return login()
def start():
    global usr__pass, usr__login
    start_a = input("Do you have an account? Yes(Y)/No(N)")

    if start_a.lower() == "y":
        login()
    else:
        reg()

start()
```

2. Передавать переменные в аргументе функции `return login(usr__login, usr__pass)`, и в самой функции забирать аргументы `def login(usr__pass, usr__login):`

Готовый код с передачей аргумента:

```
import colorama

usr__login = None
usr__pass = None


#auth form

def login(usr__pass, usr__login):
    log__row = input("Enter your login: ")
    if log__row != usr__login :
        print("Wrong login! Try again.")
        return login()
    elif log__row == usr__login :
        pass__row = input("Enter your password: ")
        if pass__row != usr__pass:
            print("Wrogn password! Try again.")
            return
        elif pass__row == usr__pass:
            print("Authorization is successful!")

#reg form

def reg():
    usr__login = input("Login: ")
    if len(usr__login) < 8 :
        print("Your login's so short, try again..")
        return reg()
    elif len(usr__login) >= 8:
        usr__pass = input("Password: ")
        if len(usr__pass) < 8:
            print("Your password's so short, try again..")
            return reg()
        elif len(usr__pass) >= 8:
            print("Good! Your account has be created.")
            return login(usr__pass, usr__login)
def start():
    start_a = input("Do you have an account? Yes(Y)/No(N)")

    if start_a.lower() == "y":
        login(usr__pass, usr__login)
    else:
        reg()

start()
```

Дальше я ввёл некоторые поправки в ваш код:

1. В вашем коде, в первом вопросе есть ответ `Y/N`, но если человек вводит `y`, то программа воспринимает это как `N`. Вот решение `if start_a.lower() == "y":`. Про метод `.lower` и другие можете прочитать [здесь](https://coderoad.ru/16643166/string-lower-%D0%B2-Python-3)
2. В функции `reg()`, а точнее там, где программа пишет `print("Your password's so short, try again..")` вместо `usr__pass = input("Password: ")` предлагаю написать `return reg()`
3. У вас ошибка в функции `login()`, точнее в присваивании `pass_row = input("Enter your password: ")`. В названии переменной вы пропустили `_`. Правильная строчка `pass__row = input("Enter your password: ")`

Answer (score 1):

Откуда эта порочная практика использовать две подряд подчеркушки в названии переменных???

Вот тут:

```
pass_row = input("Enter your password: ")
```

одна подчеркушка в pass_row

а вот тут:

```
pass__row != usr__pass:
```

уже две.

Для начала исправьте эти ошибки.

Comment: Спасибо)
Конкретно эту ошибку исправил)

Comment: @julyishard Вам,  как новичку на этом сайте, подсказываю: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Понял)
Но вопрос так и не решен, не поможете разобраться?)

Comment: @julyishard -  возникает вопрос - вы свой код с ами, перед тем, как размещать его тут, хоть запускали? Как-же в нем могли остаться синтаксические ошибки?

Comment: Запускал. Он работал, правда немного не так)

Answer (score 1):

```
def reg():
    usr__login = input("Login: ")
```

Это у вас локальная переменная, не имеющая никакого отношения к глобальной переменной с тем же именем. После выполнения функции `reg()` у вас данные, занесённые в локальные переменные этой функции `usr__login` и `usr__pass` никуда потом не передаются. Когда вы из этой функции вызываете потом `login()`, она не видит этих переменных, она видит глобальные, которые по-прежнему пустые. Исправить можно так, но по-хорошему "у вас тут всю систему менять надо":

```
def reg():
    global usr__login, usr__pass
```

Почему функция `login` видит глобальные переменные, а `reg` - локальные? Потому что `login` только читает эти переменные, а `reg` их записывает. Если переменные записываются, то без объявления их через `global` они считаются локальными. А если вы только читаете переменные, то они считаются глобальными по умолчанию в питоне.

По-хорошему же вам нужно:

- не использовать глобальные переменные, лучше используйте вызов функций с параметрами и возврат результатов работы функции через `return`, а если лениво это всё, то хотя бы внесите эти функции в некий класс, пусть у них будут общие переменные экземпляра класса, это всё-равно лучше, чем глобальные переменные
- не использовать рекурсию, там где можно обойтись циклом, например, `while True:` с выходом из цикла по `break` или `return`, рано или поздно у вас будет задача, где рекурсия войдёт на слишком большую глубину и тогда интерпретатор питона просто вылетит по ошибке и это толком никак не лечится, лучше рекурсию учиться сразу никогда не использовать